# Uniqueness conjecture for integer triples

Tags: nt.number-theory

The triple $(a,b,c)$ with $a \ge b \ge 1$ is an HT (Hikorski Triple) if 
$c = (a b+1)/(a+b)$ is an integer. The triples $(n,1,1)$ are the trivial HTs.

Conjecture: if $(a,b,c)$ and $(p,q,r)$ are both non-trivial HTs, 
then $a b c = p q r$ implies $(a,b,c) = (p,q,r)$.

That is, the product of the elements of a non-trivial HT is unique.

Any help gratefully received.

The thesis of the OP (which is not me) shows why the question is interesting, and is available at [link](http://www.s253053503.websitehome.co.uk/jg-msc-uea/thesis-final-11-2-2012.pdf)

Comment: So in other words you are looking at integer solutions to $(a+b)c=ab+1$, $(p+q)r=pq+1$, $abc=pqr$. This is a three-dimensional algebraic variety, and you want solutions outside the surfaces $a=p,b=q,c=r$ and $a=q,b=p,c=r$. Also there's a positivity condition.

Comment: Adding to Will's comment, you've got a subvariety of type $(2,2,3)$ in $\mathbb{P}^6$. If its non-singular (which can undoubtedly be checked), then it's canonical bundle is trivial, and then Vojta's conjecture would imply that the integral points on the affine piece if you set one of the coordinates equal to 1 is not Zariski dense. In general finding the integral points on a 3-dim'l variety is very hard. You might try fibering over the simpler variety $(Ac-1)c=(Sr-r)r$ by setting $A=a+b$ and $S=p+q$, with then $ab=Ac-1$ and $pq=Sr-1$, i.e., use the symmetry in $a,b$ and $p,q$.

Comment: @JoeSilverman It's singular. Let $z$ be the other variable we use to projectivize, then $a=0$, $b=0$, $p=0$, $q=0$, $z=0$ is a singular curve because the derivatives of the last equation vanish.

Comment: Many thanks, Will and Professor Silverman, much appreciated. One more comment; if x, y, f(x,y)... represents the recurrence u_(n+1)=f(u_(n-1),u_n), with u_0 = x, u_1 = y, then x, y, -(xy+1)/(x+y)... is cyclic (a Lyness cycle) period 3. The curve xy(xy+1)/(x+y) = k is of genus 1, so the conjecture above would, if true, give a family of elliptic curves as k varies, each with exactly the same number of easily found integral points. The unlikelihood of this situation perhaps makes the conjecture unlikely.

Comment: @WillSawin Good point, I wonder if it's still Kodaira dimension 0 after one desingularizes. --- To JonnyGriffiths: According to a heuristic argument of Lang, "most" elliptic curves should have no integral points; and similarly "most" elliptic curves with some obvious integral points should have no others. Of course, proving this for any particular family may not be so easy.